# How to create MapInfo Tab file using external data (XML, SQL Server) with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, gis, mapinfo

I need a way to create MapInfo tab (and associated files, IDX, DAT etc) package using .NET (C Sharp) and preferably, an open source (free) library?

I have some data with associated GIS (longitude/latitude etc) informtion and I want to create MapInfo files so that users can visualize the data.

I need to create several layers with different features (lines and points) each with its own styles corresponding to associated data.

Thanks!

Tomer

Answer (score 1):

I've found that making a such files is possible with ThinkGeo library though it can only do basic layer and not the required formatting... I assume that with MapInfo API it is possible as well... keep on searching for a solution

Comment: Tomer, It is indeed possible using the MapInfo API. How we do it is to produce "a set of MID/MIF files" (one MID/MIF pair per geometryType and distinctAttributeSet) and then use the MapInfo.Application COM-object to import them into MapInfo tables. This is reliable, (relatively) MI-version-independent, and fast-enough... We produce maps for the whole of Queensland in 33 minutes </skite;-)  I actually came here because I'm trying to figure out how to embed a MapInfo Map into my C# app, so we can "preview" the styles (on one real map) BEFORE we run the big "translation" for the whole state.

Comment: @corlettk, thanks for the reply and sorry for not seeing this sooner. I think what you suggest require some MapInfo installation which I was trying to avoid... As for the C# app (if still relevant)- according to my search, the best I've found is the one above - was easy to get (trial), to use and very responsive pre-sale/support. There are some others but not sure I did not try (or couldn't get) them.

Comment: Yes it requires a MapInfo licence. We now (optionally) use the mitab.maptools.org/ library to write tab (etc) files directly, because it's a LOT quicker... but for some reason the positional accuracy of mitab-translated datasets is unacceptably poor (we need 10^-9 degrees, or +/- 0.6mm, and mitab is as bad as 10^-4 degrees, yeah WTTF?) whereas "native MapInfo imports" are accurate enough, just. I think I probably just need to tell mitab to use a bounding box (i.e MBR), but I can't work-out how.